# How to change the optimization level?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the project which uses my second project as a lib. I see that them two has `optimization level` for debug `none -o0` and for the release `fast -0s`

but in spite of this in the log, I see such a message

> ... was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.

What are possible ways to fix it?

**P.S.** should be mentioned that debug doesn't work. It stops on the breakpoint, but I don't see the values of variables.

**UPD**

`my second project` - it is a lib. The structure looks like this

[image]

`Demo` - is a project

`Lib` - is lib

Let me know if I missed something

Comment: What does "uses my second project as a lib" mean?

Comment: So does this "lib" have a scheme? Is its Run step configured to use the Debug config?

Comment: @matt I am not sure about it, how can I check it?

Comment: You know what a scheme is, yes? So look at the "lib" scheme and see. If it has a scheme.

Comment: @matt I am new to iOS. I checked the scheme (Product -> Schemes -> Manage Schemes) I see that both lib and project have a scheme. Did you mean it?

Comment: Yes, that's where the build process decides whether to use the Debug configuration (not optimized) or the Release configuration (optimized) when you do a Run build. Which are you using? If Debug, and if the build settings say that Debug uses not optimized, then that's not the cause of the issue. :)

Comment: Also, what is this lib? Is it a framework? Is the framework already built? If so, that's where this happened: the framework was built with optimization.

Comment: @matt oh, yes it was a problem. In the run, it was set to `Release` after I changed it to `Debug` both lib and proj it starts to show debug values of the variables. Would you like to post as an answer?

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it was so easy to solve. :) Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build settings are tied to *configurations*. In your build settings for optimization, the Debug configuration is set to nonoptimized, and the Release configuration is set to optimized.

So far, so good.

But *which* configuration are you actually using when you build? That is determined by the *scheme*. Use the Scheme Editor to look at the schemes for your different targets. (You will have to look at them one at a time.) In each, look in the Run action. It says which configuration to use. If the pop-up says Release, change it to Debug.